# How to make an inputbox and text file appear in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a program that allows users to see information on songs, play an excerpt of them, and purchase selected ones.

And allow users to click the Purchase button to buy the indicated tune.

When checking out:

Users cannot checkout if they have not purchased any tunes, however they can exit the program.

Use an InputBox so that users can enter their sales tax rate. Since users are entering a value, you must perform data validation on their input.

Allow users to cancel the check out process by clicking the InputBox Cancel button.

When the input box is displayed, the textbox should have the focus, and when an incorrect tax value is added, the incorrect value should be cleared and the textbox should have focus again.

Use Write/Writeline to create a purchase order text file named PurchaseOrder.txt that includes the date the file was created and an itemized list of purchases, the subtotal, tax, and total.

When I click on the **"Purchase" button** of the selected song and click on the **"Check Out" button**, I get an error that say: **"You have not ordered any items".** Please refer to the cmdCheckOut_Click subroutine in the code below. I think that's where I'm getting my errors.

Here's the code:

```
Public Structure musicInfo
    <VBFixedString(30)> Public title As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public artist As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public genre As String
    <VBFixedString(10)> Public duration As String
    Public year As Integer
    Public price As Double
    <VBFixedString(15)> Public songFileName As String
End Structure

Public Const NoOfTunes = 5
Public songs(NoOfTunes - 1) As musicInfo

Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmTunes
Public index As Integer
Public purchaseCount As Integer
Public purchasePrice(10) As Decimal
Public purchaseTitle(10) As String


Private Sub frmTunes_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim i As Integer

    FileOpen(1, "music.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , Len(songs(0)))
    For i = 0 To NoOfTunes - 1
        FileGet(1, songs(i))
    Next
    FileClose(1)

    cmdPrevious.Visible = False

    DisplaySong(0)
End Sub

Sub DisplaySong(ByVal i As Int32)
    lblTitle.Text = songs(i).title
    lblArtist.Text = songs(i).artist
    lblGenre.Text = songs(i).genre
    lblDuration.Text = songs(i).duration
    lblYear.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).year)
    lblPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).price)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPurchase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPurchase.Click
    purchaseTitle(purchaseCount) = lblTitle.Text
    purchasePrice(purchaseCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text)
    purchaseCount = (purchaseCount + 1)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
    index = (index - 1)
    If (index < 4) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = True
    End If
    If (index = 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = False
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    index = (index + 1)
    If (index = NoOfTunes - 1) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = False
    End If
    If (index > 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = True
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPlay.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(songs(index).songFileName)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCheckOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCheckOut.Click
    Dim decimal1 As Decimal
    Dim decimal3 As Decimal
    Dim decimal4 As Decimal
    Dim str1 As String = ""
    If (Not purchaseCount) Then
        MsgBox("You have not ordered any items!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Order Error")
    Else
        Do While ((IsNumeric(str1) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0)) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0))
            str1 = InputBox("Enter your tax rate as a % between and including 0 - 10:", "Tax Rate", "", -1, -1)
            If (str1 <> "") Then
                If (Not IsNumeric(str1)) Then
                    MsgBox("You must enter a numeric tax rate", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                Else
                    Dim dec3 As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(str1)
                    If ((Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0)) Then
                        MsgBox("You must enter a tax rate between and including 0% - 10%", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        Dim StreamWriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("PurchaseOrder.txt")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("For Purchases dated: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
        StreamWriter.WriteLine()
        Dim num2 As Integer = (purchaseCount - 1)
        Dim num1 As Integer = 0
        Do While (num1 <= num2)
            StreamWriter.Write(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(Me.purchasePrice(num1), Decimal) & "     "))
            StreamWriter.WriteLine(Me.purchaseTitle(num1))
            Dim dec1 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(Nothing, Me.purchasePrice(num1))
            num1 = (num1 + 1)

        Loop
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal1, Decimal) & "  Subtotal"))
        Dim decimal2 As Decimal = New Decimal(((Convert.ToDouble(decimal3) * 0.01) * Convert.ToDouble(decimal1)))
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal2, Decimal) & "  Tax"))
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        Dim dec4 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(decimal1, decimal2)
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal4, Decimal) & "  Total"))
        MsgBox("Purchase Order has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        StreamWriter.Close()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: instead of `If (Not purchaseCount) Then` try `If purchaseCount = 0 Then...`

Answer (score 5):

`Not` doesn't do what you think it does.  In VB.Net the [Not operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2cwcswt4.aspx) performs a bitwise invert on non-boolean value.  So if `purchaseCount = 1` then `Not purchaseCount = 0xFFFFFFFE = -2`, which with convert to `True`.  Only an integer value of 0, whould convert to false.

Change the test `If (Not purchaseCount)` to `If (purchaseCount = 0)`

Comment: After doing that I'm getting an error on this line of code:

    StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal1, Decimal) & "  Subtotal"))

Comment: are we to guess WHICH error???? try this `StreamWriter.WriteLine(decimal1.ToString("C2") & " Subtotal")`

Comment: @user2943057 - you have your parenthesis in the wrong places.  StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal1, Decimal)) & " Subtotal")

Comment: But now the inputbox isn't showing up after making a song purchase. Why is that?

Comment: No clue - try tracing your code in the debugger and see why it isn't hitting.